# AWS EC2 :Connection to refused to upstream server when using nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, backend

I have deployed my backend services using docker-compose on the EC2 instance . I have no issues running the services locally but on deployment i am able to access nginx (with http)
but accessing other services through nginx as revere proxy throws connection refused error .

Here's the error by nginx :

```
2024/02/04 21:52:27 [error] 30#30: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 14.139.240.252, server: backend, request: "GET /api/v1/user/auth/google/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.3:4000/api/v1/user/auth/google/", host: "ec2-13-126-223-162.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

Here's the nginx configuration :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    include mime.types;
    gzip on;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/xml application/x-www-form-urlencoded multipart/form-data;
    gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;

    upstream mail-service {
        server mail-service:3000;
    }

    upstream auth-service {
        server auth-service:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name backend;

        location /api/v1/mail/ {
            proxy_pass http://mail-service;
            proxy_buffers 16 4k;
            proxy_buffer_size 2k;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        
        location /api/v1/send/ {
            proxy_pass http://mail-service;
            proxy_buffers 16 4k;
            proxy_buffer_size 2k;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        location /api/v1/user/ {
            proxy_pass http://auth-service;
            proxy_buffers 16 4k;
            proxy_buffer_size 2k;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

All my services are correctly starting up and i have no issue running this locally .